# Series of $\, _2F_1\left(-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n};\frac{1}{n}+1;-1\right)$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, asymptotics

I am trying the series expansion of this function :
$$f(n)=\, _2F_1\left(-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n};\frac{1}{n}+1;-1\right)\text{at}\; \infty$$

This comes from : find an asymptotic series for this integral

$$I(n)=\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt[n]{1+x^n}dx$$
By using Mathematica, I could find $$I(n)=1+\frac{\pi^2}{12n^2}-\frac{5\zeta(3)}{8n^3}+\frac{x}{n^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^5}\right)$$

But I can't find what is $x$ equals to. So, I want to ask how to get that asymptotic series and can we use elementary method to find an asymptotic series for this integral? Thank you for your time and your help.

Comment: In your opinion, should the answer contain $x$ in it?

Comment: @Aruralreader Hello, thank you for your comment. $x$ is a number was generated by Mathematica when this software gave the series for me, but $x$ is a combination of derivative of hypergeometric function and Mathematica cant find the closed form of $x$ by itself. So I need help to find $x$ or elementary method to find an asymptotic series for this integral.

Comment: I have only: $$-\frac{3 \text{Li}_5\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\text{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \log (8)-\frac{3 \zeta (5)}{16}-\frac{1}{12} \pi ^2 \left(2 \zeta (3)+\log ^3(2)\right)+\frac{21}{16} \zeta (3) \log
   ^2(2)+\frac{\log ^5(2)}{10}}{n^5}+\frac{72 \text{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-63 \zeta (3) \log (2)+\pi ^4-3 \log ^4(2)+3 \pi ^2 \log ^2(2)}{24 n^4}-\frac{5 \zeta (3)}{8 n^3}+\frac{\pi ^2}{12
   n^2}+1$$

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk Thank you for your comment. That is exactly what I want to know, it seems very hard to get that by using elementary result doesn't it? Can you please show how you get this?

Comment: Asymptotics is usually much easier on the integral representation. So recognizing that the integral is a hypergeometric function is not so useful in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By performing the change of integration variables from $x$ to $t$ via $x^n = t$, followed by integration by parts, we arrive at
$$
\int_0^1 {(1 + x^n )^{1/n} \mathrm{d}x}  = \frac{1}{n}\int_0^1 {(1 + t)^{1/n} t^{1/n - 1}  \mathrm{d}t}  = 2^{1/n}  - \frac{1}{n}\int_0^1 {(1 + t)^{1/n - 1} t^{1/n}  \mathrm{d}t}. 
$$
Now, observe that
$$
2^{1/n}  = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{\log ^k 2}}{{k!}}\frac{1}{{n^k }}} 
$$
and
$$
(1 + t)^{1/n - 1} t^{1/n}  = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{k!}}\frac{{\log ^k ((1 + t)t)}}{{1 + t}}\frac{1}{{n^k }}} 
$$
for any $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ and $0 < t < 1$. Consequently, we can expand $I(n)$ as
$$
I(n) = 1 + \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{a_k}{n^k} 
$$
for any $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, with
$$
a_k=\frac{\log ^k 2}{k!} - \frac{1}{(k - 1)!}\int_0^1 \frac{\log ^{k - 1} ((1 + t)t)}{1 + t} \mathrm{d}t.
$$
The coefficients $a_k$ can be represented using polylogarithms and values of the Riemann zeta function, thus yielding the coefficients as provided in the comments.

To list the first five coefficients, you can use the following Wolfram Mathematica commands:

```
a[k_]:=Simplify[(Log[2])^k/k!-1/(k-1)!Integrate[(Log[t(1+t)])^(k-1)/(1+t),{t,0,1}]]

Table[a[k],{k,1,5}]
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your comment. I now understand how to derive coefficients of this integral's asymptotic. Good day sir.